# Reset Input Value After Unchecking Box Javascript?

Tags: javascript, events, addeventlistener

Here is my JS code

```
let items = 0;

document.addEventListener("click", ({ target }) => {
  if (target.className === "food" && target.checked) {
    parseInt(items)
    items += target.value;
    console.log("I clicked the item", items);
  } else if (target.className === "food" && !target.checked) {
    parseInt(items)
    items -= target.value;
    console.log("i unclicked", items);
  })}
```

HTML Input

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="item1" value="1000" class="food">
 <input type="checkbox" name="item2" value="2000" class="food">
```

Right now when I click a checkbox it will add 1000, then when I uncheck it to turns to 2000, then checking again it becomes 3000, and basically just keeps adding them regardless if I check or uncheck

How do I reset the value when I uncheck my input?

Update: I added parseInt and it shows 01000 when I click my checkbox, but when I uncheck it becomes 0. However, if I click 1 checkbox, then another it will add it like 10002000 instead of doing 3000

Comment: Swap `items -= -target.value` for `items -= target.value` (remove the unary operation) - you're effectively adding the numbers regardless. ***e.g.*** `1 - (-1)` is equivalent to `1 + 1`

Comment: nah thats there because if I remove it it becomes 100020003000 instead of just 1000

Comment: [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: Subtracting a negative number is still adding a positive number. How about subtracting a positive number OR adding a negative number?

Comment: how does using parseInt vs my method change the result of getting the exact same result of 1000?

Comment: You complained about 100020003000. That only happens if you try to add strings. parseInt converts to an integer. Use it instead of prefixing target.value with a + or a -.

Comment: yes but the issue is when I add parseINT it only affects one checkbox, but if I click a 2nd checkbox it adds it like 10002000

Comment: Do you want to add 1000 when you check the box and subtract upon unchecking or the other way around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```js
let items = 0;

document.addEventListener("click", ({ target }) => {
  if (target.className === "food" && target.checked) {
    items += parseInt(target.value);
    console.log("I clicked the item", items);
  } else if (target.className === "food" && !target.checked) {
    items -= parseInt(target.value);
    console.log("i unclicked", items);
  }})
```

```html
 <input type="checkbox" name="item1" value="1000" class="food">
 <input type="checkbox" name="item2" value="2000" class="food">
```

Comment: ah I see I added parseInt in the wrong spot

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively without the parseInt:

```
let items = 0;

document.addEventListener("click", ( {target} ) => {
  if (target.className === "food" && target.checked === true) {
    items += +target.value;
    console.log("I clicked the item", items);
  } else if (target.className === "food" && target.checked === false) {
    items -= +target.value;
    console.log("i unclicked", items);
  }});
```

Comment: this doesn't work because it doesn't reset the values on uncheck. this was my original code from my question

Comment: No, it's not the same. Just try it. https://jsfiddle.net/z9jw24L7/

Comment: oh you changed the false target value to a + instead of a -